# Calling multiple function in a single line in PHP

Tags: php, database

All my classes that connect to a database need to get values of custom columns from their respective tables. So instead of coding a function for each class, is there a way for me to implement a base class from which my classes extend and I can use that base class function to easily get and update data on my database (at least for simple data).

```
class Users extend BaseClass
{
    private $table = "users";
    private $columns = ["name", "email", "password"];
}
```

so from an outside function, I can access the email value like this

```
Users->where("name", "John")->getEmail();
```

or possibly

`Users->where("name", "John")->get("email");`

I could also use this method to update data to the database. The functions `where` should be universal so it should exist in `BaseClass`. (I know the database queries that I should use, what I want to know is how to call `get` after calling `where` and also possibly setting multiple where requirements).

`Users->where("name", "John")->where("last_name", "Smith")->get("email");`

Comment: This is definitely too broad for a decent answer, but it sounds like you're trying to build something very similar to Laravel's Eloquent ORM. Start with the [source code](https://github.com/illuminate/database) for that.

Comment: Third Party libraries usually are not my go to but in the case of a database abstraction ORMs are probably one of the easiest to justify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this

```
abstract class BaseClass
{
    private $where_clauses=[];
    private $columns=[];
    private $table='';

    protected function setData($table,$cols){
        $this->columns=$cols;
        $this->table=$table;
    }

    public function where($key, $value){
        $this->where_clauses[$key]=$value;
        return $this;
    }
    public function get($col){
        $sql='SELECT '.$col.' FROM '.$this->table.' WHERE';
        $first=true;
        foreach($this->where_clauses AS $key=>$val){
            if(!$first) sql.=' AND ';
            $first=false;
            $sql.=$key.' = '.$val;
        }

        // RUN QUERY, Return result
    }

}
```

Note that the `where` function returns a reference to $this, which is what let's you string the function calls together (not tested the code).  This would also need some adapting to let you put two conditions on the same column.